# Does React render all the components present in the bundle.js file on initial load?

Tags: reactjs

I've a react app with multiple components being rendered at different routes using react-router. Let's take 2 components as an example

```
<Routes>
<Route path="/"><Home /></Route>
<Route path="pay"><Pay /></Route>
</Routes>
```

Both of these components are using `useEffect`.
Does React render(and run the effect) for both the components on the initial load of the (webpack)js bundle while visiting the index path?

If so, I assume that I can use code splitting to render only the visited route's component on load.
https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, without code splitting and lazy loading, the bundle will *contain* both `Home` and `Pay` components, but `Router`/`Routes` will only mount and render one at a time, depending on the current path, i.e. if the current path is `/`, it will mount and render `Home`, and similar for the `/pay` route - `Pay` component.

*With* code splitting and lazy loading, then its possible to chunk the one bundle into multiple, e.g. one bundle for `Home`, one for `Pay` and they can each be loaded 'just-in-time' when accessing the relevant route for the component with lazy loading.  However, none of this changes the fact that `Router` will only *render* the component that is on the current path (in your example anyway, nested routes are slightly more complex, and can behave differently, and can allow you to render multiple 'route' components on the same path, often used for building up screen layouts with their content inside)

Comment: that's what I thought too. but in my project, we have a custom hook which is making a fetch call in its `useEffect` and this custom hook is being used in multiple components. it seems that multiple fetch calls are happening whenever a value in the dependency array of the `useEffect` changes.
so I assumed that all the components, even though I haven't visited their routes, are being rendered and are the reason behind these multiple calls.

Comment: are you using React v18 strict mode? if so, this can catch people out - https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: i.e it could still just be the one component rendering but its `useEffect` triggering twice